# Retrieving font name of selected text in RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, fonts, richtextbox, selectedtext

I'm trying to retrieve font names for each line of text in a RichTextBox (each line is having a different font). Below is the code that I'm using to get the font name of second line in the RTB.

```
RichTextBox2.Select(RichTextBox2.Lines(0).Length + 1, 
                    RichTextBox2.Lines(1).Length)
font = RichTextBox2.SelectionFont.Name
```

But I'm getting the font name of the first line of textbox. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the GetFirstCharIndexFromLine function to get the beginning point of each line:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox2.Lines.Count - 1
  RichTextBox2.Select(RichTextBox2.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i),
                      RichTextBox2.Lines(i).Length)
  MessageBox.Show(RichTextBox2.SelectionFont.Name)
Next
```

This is what I used to setup the RichTextBox control:

```
RichTextBox2.Clear()
RichTextBox2.SelectionFont = New Font("Segoe UI", 16)
RichTextBox2.AppendText("This is the First Line" & Environment.NewLine)
RichTextBox2.SelectionFont = New Font("Calibri", 12)
RichTextBox2.AppendText("This is the Second Line" & Environment.NewLine)
RichTextBox2.SelectionFont = New Font("Arial", 16)
RichTextBox2.AppendText("This is the Third Line" & Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: Still getting the font name of first line. Used RichTextbox2.SelectedText to verify if it is selecting the right text and it is, but the font is not showing correctly.
Thanks

Comment: @Charan I tested this code in a RichTextBox that I had three different fonts on three different lines and it reported everything correctly.